# entity framework simple subquery generates ugly sql

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to optimize the following simple Entity Framework query to retreieve all the products from the same group

```
var query = from p in ctx.Products 
            where p.GroupId == ( from q in ctx.Products 
                                 where q.Id == new Guid(".....")                                       
                                 select q.GroupId).FirstOrDefault()
            select p;
```

After checking the generated sql using SQL Server Profiler I see this query

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Code] AS [Code]
FROM       [inv].[Products] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent2].[GroupId] AS [GroupId]
    FROM [inv].[Products] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE cast('.....' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent2].[Id] ) AS [Limit1] ON 1 = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent3].[GroupId] AS [GroupId]
    FROM [inv].[Products] AS [Extent3]
    WHERE cast('.....' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent3].[Id] ) AS [Limit2] ON 1 = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent4].[GroupId] AS [GroupId]
    FROM [inv].[Products] AS [Extent4]
    WHERE cast('.....' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent4].[Id] ) AS [Limit3] ON 1 = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent5].[GroupId] AS [GroupId]
    FROM [inv].[Products] AS [Extent5]
    WHERE cast('.....' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent5].[Id] ) AS [Limit4] ON 1 = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [inv].[Products] AS [Extent6]
    WHERE cast('.....' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent6].[Id] ) AS [Limit5] ON 1 = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [inv].[Products] AS [Extent7]
    WHERE cast('.....' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent7].[Id] ) AS [Limit6] ON 1 = 1
WHERE ([Extent1].[GroupId] = (CASE WHEN ([Limit1].[GroupId] IS NULL) 
                                   THEN cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier) 
                                   ELSE [Limit2].[GroupId] END)) 
AND (CASE WHEN ([Limit3].[GroupId] IS NULL) 
          THEN cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier) 
          ELSE [Limit4].[GroupId] END IS NOT NULL)
```

Why is it generating so many identical JOINs? 
Is there any option to remove the final null casting?
Could you please suggest ways to improve the generated sql?

I've tested also with LINQPad and that one is generating normal SQL

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 UniqueIdentifier = '....'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[GroupId], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Description], [t0].[Code]
FROM [inv].[Products] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[GroupId] = ((
    SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[GroupId]
    FROM [inv].[Products] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[Id] = @p0
    ))
```

Comment: If you're getting different results in LINQPad from your app, check the version of EF you're using in each and check your code to make sure nothing is being added to the expression tree at runtime.

Comment: I'm using EF 6.0,nothing else is added to the expression tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really dealing with a primary key (id) here, I'm not sure that you need the FirstOrDefault. Would the following accomplish the same goal:

```
var query = from groupProduct in ctx.Products 
            where groupProduct.Id == someGuid // This should return only one result
            join childProduct in ctx.Products
            on groupProduct.Id equals childProduct.GroupId
            select childProduct
```

And the generated SQL is

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent2].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent2].[Code] AS [Code]
FROM  [inv].[Products] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [inv].[Products] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[GroupId]
WHERE cast('....' as uniqueidentifier) = [Extent1].[Id]
```

Comment: Indeed that is the way to go, although there is a small mistake in your code

Comment: it should be it should be on groupProduct.RecId equals childProduct.RecId and not it should be on groupProduct.RecId equals childProduct.Id

Comment: @liviumamelluc it appears that this is a self-referencing join. I think I had it flipped and fixed it. It shouldn't be where parent.pk = child.pk, but rather parent.pk = child.fk (GroupId).

Comment: It might be helpful to others to post the revised sql that this generates as a comparison. I would do it, but don't have your data model to test against.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, its two statements but should produce smoother SQL if that is what you are after:

```
var groupId = ctx.Products.Where(p=> p.Id = new Guid(...).Select(p=> p.GroupId).FirstOrDefault();

if(groupId.HasValue)
{
   var query = ctx.Products.Where(p=> p.GroupId == groupId).Select(p=> p);
}
```

This assumes that Id is an int, if it is not, use the appropriate boundary check.

Comment: Yes, it is smoother SQL, but it is making 2 round trips to SQL, and I'm  trying to optimize it

Comment: You don't have a lot of control over how EF generates the SQL, I would run some performance counters and see which performs better for you.

Comment: May be EF optimize This groupBy var query = ctx.Products.GroupBy(p => p.GroupId).Where(g => g.Any(q.Id == new Guid(".....")))